# Passing an object to an ejs loader, using html-webpack-plugin

Tags: javascript, html, webpack, ejs, html-webpack-plugin

I believe I've looked everywhere, but I've come up empty handed.
I've been using `html-webpack-plugin` to load a single `index.html` file from my source, but my client has come with some localisations, and I thought it would be great if I could add them dynamically.

So I'm trying to switch over to using a templating engine with `html-webpack-plugin`, namely `ejs`, but I'm having major problems!

I want `html-webpack-plugin` to render and `.ejs` file, and I need to give said `.ejs` file a huge object of localisations.

I want something like this:

```
<h1><%= header.title %></h1>
```

Coming from a localisation `.json`-file like this:

```
{
  "header": {
    "title": "My Clients Super Awesome Website"
  }
}
```

I've tried using two different ejs webpack loaders, and I simply can't figure out how to pass a simple object to the ejs loader, that I can use in my ejs file.

Hope you guys have some answers :D Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in index.ejs

```
<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.header.title %>
```

in webpack.config.js

```
module: {
    rules: [
    {
        test: /.ejs$/,
        loader: 'ejs-loader'
    }
]}
```

and

```
plugins: [
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    header: {title: 'test'},
    template: './index.ejs',
})]
```

Notice. do not use `options: { variable: 'data or xxx' }` after `ejs-loader`, if variable is specified, `htmlWebpackPlugin` will be unknown.

So you need use html-webpack-plugin in your webpack configuration. And put the object into HtmlWebpackPlugin's parameter.

Comment: Thanks! You're about 1.5 year late, but the answer is correct and it could be useful for other people 

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same thing. Seems like the template can access options object passed to html-webpack-plugin as `htmlWebpackPlugin.options` object.

To include eg. the title, you need to reference it from the template as `htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title`. I don't know if there any way to pass values in more plugin-agnostic way, so you can just reference `title` as `title` in the template file.

Answer (score 1):

easy insert any paramaters.

```
// webpack.config.js

    ...
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: 'index.html',
      template: 'template/index.ejs',
      templateParameters: {
        'title': 'My Clients Super Awesome Website',
        'episode: '2'
      }
    }),
    ...
```

```
<!-- index.ejs -->

<%= title %>
<%= episode %>
```